# An error occurred while installing marketplace in Eclipse;

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

Error is as follows;

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Marketplace Client - Source 1.1.1.I20110907-0947 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.source.feature.group 1.1.1.I20110907-0947)
  Missing requirement: Marketplace Client - Source 1.1.1.I20110907-0947 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.source.feature.group 1.1.1.I20110907-0947) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group [1.0.0.v201004,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Comment: What kind of plugin you're trying to install? Anyway, can you try to install the missing package yourself in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Discovery and then try it again?

Comment: That is a very old version of Marketplace, what version of Eclipse are you trying to install it in?